# Is ewasm ready here and does it mean that we do not need to use Sidity anymore?

Tags: solidity-0.8.x, ewasm

As far as l know, using ewasm will mean that you will be able to use any language for smart contracts. So does it mean Solidity won't be in use anymore? Please help me clarify that!  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Solidity is going to stick around for a while because its legacy adoption.